# Does apache livy 0.5.0 supports spark on k8s?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to run jupyter for spark on k8s.

After little experiment :) 
I found that

k8s does not support client mode

```
$ bin/spark-shell --master k8s://192.168.99.100:8443
...
...
Error: Client mode is currently not supported for Kubernetes.
```

And that

spark-shell can't run in cluster mode

```
$ bin/spark-shell --master k8s://192.168.99.100:8443 --deploy-mode cluster
...
...
Error: Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.
```

So I am guessing that *jupyter spark kernel* or *zeppelin* will not run for k8s. (not sure)

As a workaround I am thinking about using livy.

Does apache livy 0.5.0 supports spark on k8s?
Any advice for setting up spark cluster would be appreciated.

P.S. I tried to use GCP dataproc but after lost GCS shared note once (during 7 days period evaluation, no clue about reason). I am sure it's my fault (maybe on configuration?) but didn't dive deep to dive deep in k8s. :)

Comment: you need to provide spark master url in zeppelin.. In case of spark with k8s you will have a different master url.. try providing that.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#cluster-mode this might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can try customized livy-0.6.0 for that: https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/167
We've required a solution for the project to run Spark on Kubernetes and modified Livy to serve that purpose.
You can be interested in Helm chart for Livy setup either: https://github.com/jahstreet/spark-on-kubernetes-helm